# Angular directive coming in JSON

Tags: html, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive:

Here I am passing a data object:

```
<a-link options = "data"></a-link>
```

And here is my directive:

```
.directive('aLink', function() {
 return {
     restrict: 'AE',
     replace: true,
     template: '<a href = "{{href}}">{{text}}</div>',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('options', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue)
                scope.href = newValue.href;
                scope.text = newValue.text;
          });
     }
});
```

This works fine. It gives me an anchor tag like

```
<a href = "/home/login.html">link</a>
```

My question is:

If i get the following on json:

```
{
    body :  "Click <a-link text = 'here' href = '/home/login.html'></a-link>"
}
```

and my html:

```
<p ng-bind-html = "body"></p>
```

This doenot work.

How do I recompile this? Do I need to pass it through another directive and compile it there?

Answer (score 0):

Use $compile service:

```
$compile(response.body)($scope)
```